# Magento 2 - Getting wrong quantity from a simple product

Tags: product, stock, quantity

I've only recently started working with Magento and developement in general, so I am new at this. I need a (simple) product's quantity for some custom logic. But I don't know how to get it into my .phtml template. I used this function:

```
$quantity = $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

and

```
print_r($quantity);
```

to see what it returns... and it always returns 0, even if the item is in stock.

Then I tried

```
$quantity = $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData();
print_r($quantity);
```

and got this:

[image]

literally everything except what I need :D.

While researching,  I found a few people that said you need to create a module for this. Is this the only way? If so, how does one do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script will be helpful to get the product stock qty, min qty and stock details in magento2.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
print_r($productStockObj->getData());
```

Note: use of objectmanager is not good idea it's just for quick trick.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: If it's works for you then you can upvote or accept. so, other community member can find it.

Comment: "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I'll upvote when I am able to. Thanks

Comment: Can you point me to some lesson on how to do this without the use of object manager (creating a module)?

Comment: Can you point me to some lesson? - ``sure. ask another question please``